# Upload 3 different featured image sizes to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

Is there a way that on Wordpress I can upload 3 different image sizes of my featured image?  My post images are a different size in the first column rather than the second column, and I also have an owl carousel.  In 2 out of the 3 places my featured image for my post gets distorted.  So does anyone know how I can upload 3 different image sizes?

Here is what my site post layout looks like.  As you can see at the top I have an owl carousel, in column 1 I have one post, and in column 2 I have three posts.[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, just go to functions.php and defines your required size, example as below :-

```
add_image_size( 'first', 80, 80, true );
add_image_size( 'second', 120, 120, true );
add_image_size( 'third', 180, 180, true );
```

After that, you can define your required size where you want display the particular image size like below :-

```
the_post_thumbnail('first');
the_post_thumbnail('second');
the_post_thumbnail('third');
```